# Asus UX31A touch screen fails after updating to windows 8.1

Tags: windows, touch, upgrade, windows-8.1

After upgrading my Asus UX31A from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 my touch screen fails.

When I touch the screen the actual "mouse click" happens a few inches off the place I really tapped.

I already calibrated my pc, but this didn't help.

Is this a known problem? Or what can I do about it?

Comment: Same thing with me.  Hoping you get an answer.